# Is there a way for Sequelize to check if a row exists in the table, before initiating a delete action?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize ORM with NodeJS, Express & Postgres to setup CRUD APIs. My `delete` route's logic looks like this:

```
app.delete('/deleteuser/:id', authenticateJWT, (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        await User.destroy({where: {id: req.params.id}})
            .then(() => {
                console.log(`User ${req.params.id} deleted`)
                res.sendStatus(200)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
                res.sendStatus(500)
            })
    })();
})
```

This sends me a 200 OK status even if the `id` value I am passing is not present in the database. I tried setting up a count variable along with `User.count(...)` to check for row availability, with partial success. But, this seems a bit convoluted. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding to your own (@Meera) response.

This is not a workaround is actually how the library works. Destroy it will return the number of deleted rows. So for instance:

```
User.destroy({where: {name: 'X'}})
            .then(numberRows=> { 
 console.log(`${numberRows} User rows deleted`);
 res.sendStatus(numberRows?200: 406)

 });
```

[https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-destroy](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-destroy)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have a workaround. By checking the return value in the onFulfilled portion of the promise, my problem is solved:

```
app.delete('/deleteuser/:id', authenticateJWT, (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        await User.destroy({where: {id: req.params.id}})
            .then((deletedUser) => {
                if(deletedUser){
                    console.log(`User ${req.params.id} deleted`)
                    res.sendStatus(200)
                } else {
                    console.log(`User ${req.params.id} does not exist`)
                    res.sendStatus(406)
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
                res.sendStatus(500)
            })
    })();
})
```